# NodeJS - add device to BLE whitelist

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using [`@abandonware/noble`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/noble) for scanning and interrogating Bluetooth devices on Linux. I could not, however, find a method to add a MAC address to the LE whitelist, similar to `hcitool lewladd` on Linux. Is there a way to do it using `noble`?

Comment: No, it does not support white list. What do you want to use the white list for?

Comment: I am scanning for certain BLE devices and would like to have the 'discovery' callback triggered only for the whitelisted MAC addresses. At the moment I am doing manual comparison of the peripheral's ID to an array of "allowed" addresses.